# Slicing while unpacking slice

Tags: go

I have the following code

```
func Sum(a []int) int {
    res := 0
    for _, n := range a {
        res += n
    }
    return res
}

func SumAll(ns ...[]int) (sums []int) {
    for _, s := range ns {
        sums = append(sums, Sum(s))
    }
    return
}

//SumAllTails sums [:1] in each slice
func SumAllTails(sls ...[]int) []int {
    newsls := [][]int{}
    for _, sl := range sls {
        newsls = append(newsls, sl[1:])
    }
    return SumAll(newsls...)
}
```

Ideally I'd like to change the last function to be something like this

```
func SumAllTails(sls ...[]int) []int {
    return SumAll(sls[:][1:]...)
}
```

This last bit returns each slice but the first one, but what I'd like to do is unpack each slice from position 1 onwards, omitting the value at 0. Is there a way of achieving this in go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way to do what you want without going through the slices first is to write a SumAlln function:

```
func SumAlln(n int, ns ...[]int) (sums []int) {
    for _, s := range ns {
        sums = append(sums, Sum(s[n:]))
    }
    return
}

func SumAll(ns...[]int) []int {
    return SumAlln(0,ns...)
}
```

And then call `SumAlln`.

Comment: This would be one way of doing it. Does this mean there is no built in way of slicing a "subslice" while unpacking?

Comment: There is no builtin way to bulk-sublice a list of slices. You need a for-loop for that.